# Get value from void QuickFix library method

Tags: c#, quickfixn

I have a [QuickFix](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/creating-an-application) Application in C#:

```
    public class MyQuickFixApp : IApplication
    {
        ...
        public void ToApp(Message msg, SessionID sessionID) 
        { 
            string s = msg.GetString(Tags.ClOrdID);
            ...
        }
        public void FromApp(Message msg, SessionID sessionID) { }
    }
```

where the message to other Fix Server is sent from `ToApp` and the reply is comming to `FromApp`.
I need to store the tag value of a sent message (`s`) to select the corresponding reply. `ToApp` method is returning void. I tried to store the value in a public static filed, but it fails. 

Looks like the follows:

```
    public class MyQuickFixApp : IApplication
    {
        ...
        public static string currClOrdID = ""; 
        public void ToApp(Message msg, SessionID sessionID) 
        { 
            string s = msg.GetString(Tags.ClOrdID);
            currClOrdID = s;
            ...
        }
        public void FromApp(Message msg, SessionID sessionID) 
        { 
            if (Equals(currClOrdID)) ...
        }
    }
```

I am getting `NullreferenceException` on the `currClOrdID`. What is the general strategy to do it? Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

As per [QuickFix/n Tutorial](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/receiving-messages.html):

> The best way to write an app is with the specific, strongly typed Message and Field classes

So you could use `Crack(...);` in `FromApp`:

```
using QuickFix;

public class MyApplication : MessageCracker, IApplication
{
    public void FromApp(Message msg, SessionID sessionID)
    {
        Crack(msg, sessionID);
    }
    //...
}
```

Regarding `ClOrdID`, you could extract it from the message and directly pass it to processing function, it is safer than keeping `ClOrdID` in static variable in multi-threaded message processing.

For example (assuming you need to process `ExecutionReport` message):

```
public void OnMessage(QuickFix.FIX44.ExecutionReport msgReport, SessionID sessionID)
{
    string clOrdID = msgReport.ClOrdID.getValue();
    ...
    YourProcessing(clOrdID, ...);
}
```

Notice that `OnMessage(...)` will be called from `Crack(msg, sessionID);`

If you need to store additional data for processing the received message, I would use a dictionary, as you may have several messages pending, and the responses may arrive in unpredictable order. Also it seems logical to store such data close to (and before) calling `Send` rather then in `ToApp`, like below (assuming you are sending an order for execution, expecting `ExecutionReport` in reply):

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ...> _orderData = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ...>();

public bool PlaceNewOrder(...)
    {
        string clOrdID = ...;
        QuickFix.FIX44.NewOrderSingle msgOrder = 
            new QuickFix.FIX44.NewOrderSingle(new ClOrdID(clOrdID), ...);
        ...;
        _orderData.TryAdd(clOrdID, <data required for later processing>);
        // Notice the data is stored before sending the message
        // so it will be available to process a response
        Session.SendToTarget(msgOrder, sessionID);
    }
```

When processing a response message you could retrieve the data stored for this particular `clOrdID`:

```
private void YourProcessing(clOrdID, ...)
{
    ...;
    _orderData.TryGetValue(clOrdID, out ...);
    // You may want to check return value to make sure the data was stored for this clOrdID...
    ...;
}
```

Also notice that at some point you should clean up the dictionary, for example when you know from processed message, that it is the final one, and do not expect any more messages for this `ClOrdID`.